# How to handle capybara cucumber dynamic content

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have this HTML/JS code:

```
<script>
  function sync()
  {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('textArea');
    var n2 = document.getElementById('textArea2');
    n2.value = n1.value;
  }
</script>


<h1>TESTING PAGE</h1>

<div>
  Edit text:
  </br>
  <textarea id="textArea" rows="4" cols="50" >Input text to copy...</textarea>
  </br>
  <button id="copyButton" type="button" onclick="sync()">Copy Text</button>
  </br>
  </br>
  <textarea id="textArea2" rows="4" cols="50">  </textarea>
  </br>
  <a href="testPage2.html">Link to next page</a>
</div>
```

As you can see, I just copy the content from a textbox to another textbox when pressing a button. I use Javascript to do that.

When I try to get the text from both textboxes to compare them, the ".text" method only gives me the text the boxes had when the page was loaded, and not the text I add after that.

How would you access the elements after changing them so that I can get the current text content?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to get the text from the textboes? Please share you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text` method gets the descendant text node content of of a specified element. 
 That's not what you want with form fields, instead you want `value`

```
find('#textArea2').value
```

That being said, you really shouldn't be just getting the value and comparing with ==/eq since it can lead to flaky tests if your JS is slow. You'll be better off long term using the Capybara provided matchers/assertions like

```
val = find('#textArea').value
click_button('Copy Text')
expect(page).to have_field('textArea2', with: val) # RSpec    
# assert_field('textArea2', with: val) # minitest
```

Comment: Many thanks! I'm still learning how to use Capybara so your input is well appreciated!